# CouchDB Insert and Update Performance

Tags: python, couchdb, nosql

sorry for bad English first. :(

I'm using CouchDB form several months in develop mode, when we wanner make it in production env, we found some performance problem, It's takes 7 seconds for 1000 documents inserts and updates (because I use cache here or it will take much longer).

I know I could use bulk update but I can't, because our Object Design is like this:

(in Python)

```
class Props(object):
    def __set__(self, name, value):
        # this is a setter, and update couched
        couchdb.update(database, name, value)

class User(object):
    name = Props('name' + self.id)
```

Then I could use code like this

```
user = User()
user.name = 'CouchDB'
```

then It will save 'CouchDB' in database 'test_somedatabase' with document id 'name10000' and value {'name': 'CouchDB'}

This is easy to read and understand, but It will cause performance problem if I do like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    user.name = 'something'
```

It's there better way to solve this Problem? Can I use TCP in socket instead of HTTP?

THANKS!

Comment: Didn't fully understand. Are you persisting something every time someone changes a property? If so, I do not think a document oriented DB is your best pick. Although, I do not know how you would consume the data, but maybe a better pick would be something that is key-value. Or perhaps CouchBase which handles both.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is HTTP only and even if there is TCP, making 1000 calls is always slower then just making 1. If you really care about performance, you should reconsider bulk document update api.